# Run an Ansible task to all hosts if at least one of the hosts has a variable

Tags: ansible

I want to run a task to all hosts if at least one of the hosts has a variable "new_node".
For example i have inventory

```
[all]
host1.example.net
host2.example.net
host3.example.net new_node=True
```

And if in one of the hosts has variable "new_node=True"
then run this task on all hosts

```
---
- hosts: all

  tasks:
     - name: Create file yep at all hosts
       file:
         path: /tmp/yep
         state: file
```

What condition or filter should i apply? Any ideas. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[extract](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#selecting-values-from-arrays-or-hashtables) the variables, [select](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/master/templates/#select) `true` items and evaluate the test [is any](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tests.html#testing-if-a-list-value-is-true), e.g.

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        semaphore: "{{ ansible_play_hosts_all|
                       map('extract', hostvars, 'new_node')|
                       select is any }}"
      run_once: true
```

gives `true` if any variable `new_node` is `true` and gives `false` otherwise

```yaml
  semaphore: true
```

Then use the variable `semaphore` in the conditions e.g.

```yaml
      when: semaphore|bool
```

---

**Filter select explained**

Quoting from [select](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/master/templates/#select)

> *"If no test is specified, each object will be evaluated as a boolean."*

Given the inventory

```yaml
shell> cat hosts
host1.example.net
host2.example.net new_node=False
host3.example.net new_node=True
```

The task extracts the variables

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ ansible_play_hosts_all|
                 map('extract', hostvars, 'new_node')|
                 list }}"
```

```yaml
  msg: '[Undefined, False, True]'
```

We don't have to care about `Undefined` because `select()` evaluates `Undefined` to `False`

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ ansible_play_hosts_all|
                 map('extract', hostvars, 'new_node')|
                 select|list }}"
```

```yaml
  msg:
  - true
```

You can test the evaluation of `Undefined` to `False` separately, e.g.

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ ansible_play_hosts_all|
                 map('extract', hostvars, 'new_node')|
                 map('bool')|
                 list }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  msg:
  - false
  - false
  - true
```

---

If no variable is defined

```yaml
shell> cat hosts
host1.example.net
host2.example.net
host3.example.net
```

`select` returns an empty list

```yaml
  msg: '[Undefined, Undefined, Undefined]'
```

```yaml
  msg: []
```

Comment: Thanks. Looks good. But i'm set select('defined') instead select is any because some vars not defined and i get exception

Comment: finaly ```semaphore: "{{ ansible_play_hosts_all | map('extract', hostvars, 'new_node') |select('defined') | select is any}}"```

Comment: You can't get an `undefined` exception on select(). Without any filter `select()` evaluates the item as Boolean. In this case, `undefined` simply evaluates to `false` and won't be selected i.e. `select('defined')` is redundant in the pipe.

Comment: I don't know what I'm doing wrong, but when i use this debug  `- debug:
        msg: "{{ ansible_play_hosts_all|
                 map('extract', hostvars, 'new_node')|
                 select|list }}" `  i got an error `fatal: [host1.example.net]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'ansible.vars.hostvars.HostVarsVars object' has no attribute 'new_node'\n\nThe error appears to be in '/home/user/myrepo/ansible/examples/test.yml': line 10, column 7, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe }`

Answer (score 1):

You can create a variable, that will be set to `true` when one of the hosts in `[all]` group has the variable `new_node` defined. Then this variable can be used to conditionally run the task.

Example:

```yaml
  tasks:
  - set_fact:
      run_on_all: true
    when: hostvars[item]['new_node']|default(false)
    with_items: "{{ groups['all'] }}"

  - file:
      path: /tmp/yep
      state: touch
    when: run_on_all|default(false)
```

The first task, sets the variable `run_on_all` to `true` if any one of the hosts has the variable `new_node=True`. Then the next task will execute if the previous task set the `run_on_all` variable to `true`. I am using the `default()` filter to avoid the chances of the variables being "undefined".

Comment: Very nIce, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You did not actually specify what should happen if this property was not present, so I will assume you would simply want to abort the play in that case.

Simplest solution that I could think of is to set the playbook to run against the group `[all]`, and check if this property is present on any of the hosts. If it is *not* present on any hosts, you abort the play.

Example

```yaml
---
- hosts: all

  tasks:
    - name: Check if the hostvar 'new_node' is present on any hosts
      set_fact:
        has_new_node: "{{ groups['all'] | map('extract', hostvars, 'new_node') | list | select('defined') | length | bool }}"
      delegate_to: localhost
    
    - name: Abort play if not 'has_new_node'
      meta: end_play
      when: not has_new_node

    - debug:
        msg: new_node found
```